# How to properly dismount VeraCrypt volumes in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, veracrypt

I am attempting to properly dismount two VeraCrypt volumes from Linux.

Alas, it doesn't work. Every subsequent boot into Windows I am prompted to check the file system as it allegedly hasn't been cleanly unmounted. So far the checks never turned up any issues, though.

So I have a systemd unit like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unmounting VeraCrypt volumes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/unmount-veracrypt-volumes.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the script called from `ExecStop` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/logger "Unmounting VeraCrypt volumes"
/usr/bin/veracrypt --text --dismount
/usr/bin/logger "Unmounting VeraCrypt volumes (using umount)"
for mnt in 1 2; do
        if /bin/mountpoint -q /media/username/$mnt; then
                umount /media/username/$mnt
        fi
done
/usr/bin/logger "Unmounting VeraCrypt volumes (using umount -f)"
for mnt in 1 2; do
        if /bin/mountpoint -q /media/username/$mnt; then
                umount --force /media/username/$mnt
        fi
done
```

What am I missing? How can I achieve for these volumes to dismount cleanly?

If it matters, one of the volumes is FAT32, the other exFAT. Oh and the VeraCrypt version is 1.22.

Comment: Could it be a timing thing between unmounting the file system and closing the container?

Comment: @jc__ You mean I should deliberately wait some longer prior to dismounting?

Comment: just thinking... When you unmount the file system the cache may not be cleared before the veracrypt container is closed. Assume the file system unmount is async...

Comment: Okay, I may be entirely wrong, but isn't the whole purpose of an unmount to flush the cache and _then_ make the volume unavailable? Now for `umount --force` I would agree, that probably skips some otherwise taken steps. But that part of the script is practically never executed (the conditional part below the `veracrypt` stanza). But your comment gave me another - related - idea. I'll try to verify that and if it works out, answer my own question. Thank you kindly for your input!